# Creating 2D binary matrix in JAVA

Tags: java, matrix, binary, 2d

Could anybody explain to me, how would I be able to create a two-dimensional binary matrix, that has fields that can have a value (1) or value (0) in it's block.

I am trying to write a code for my assignment in java and I must create a binary matrix. And the matrix consists of rows and collumns that are given at the beginning.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Why 1 or 0 and not true or false instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a 2d boolean array, so only two values are allowed (true or false):

```
boolean[][] matrix = new boolean[rows][columns];
```

Or use a 2d short array that allow more of 2 values, but you can put on it the value 0 and 1:

```
short[][] matrix = new short[rows][columns];
```

Or use byte object:

```
byte[][] matrix = new byte[rows][columns];
```

Comment: So if i understood correcctly the two values in your code [10][10] stand for number of rows and collums?

Comment: You probably guessed by now that I am a beginner at programming. But would would I implement rows and colloms that scanner object reads. for example int collomn = sc.nextInt(); and int row = sc.nextInt(); would it be proper to make ... = new boolean[collomn][row];

Comment: I am also trying to make a row of char ... example: char[] row = sc.next().toCharArray(); and char[] colomn = sc.next().toCharArray(); that way the both numbers of row and colomns are read by scanner ... but how would I merge this to values into one 2D matrix?

Comment: Sorry i haven't understand what is your problem... Please use an easy-english

Comment: You're not going to create a matrix by reading one row and one column and merging them.  A matrix is multiple rows, each with the same number of columns (or alternatively, multiple columns, each with the same number of rows).

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.*;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    char[] row = sc.next().toCharArray();
    char[] colomn = sc.next().toCharArray();


    char[][] matrix = new matrix[row][colomn];

}
```

This is what I have so far, but it it far from correct. Don't know what to change to make 2D array